# Change the second color of occurrence in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, colors

I have an issue, in Eclipse, I try to change the second color for occurrences, but I can't:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFFjB.png]

I always want it to be dark red, not grey. How can I fix it? I searched a lot but 'General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations -> Occurrences' won't do the trick.

Comment: What do you mean by *second* color?

Comment: Which color you want to change. All occurrences will be marked in the same color.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to change it in 'General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations -> Occurrences'. The first time it did not work. I've opened the window again, changed the color, clicked 4 or 5 times on apply, then OK, the editors were reloaded and it worked in the first editor... Finally I restarted eclipse and now it's OK, the 2nd color has been changed!